# How to get the print Prieview of page with window.print()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I am trying to get the print preview of page using button like:

```
<input type="button" value="Print in javascript" onclick="window.print();"/>
```

It is working in seome percentage. But I am not getting 100% print preview, it drops some content while prieviwing.

Is there any thing which I am not doing correctly?

Comment: if ya talkin about that you dont see colors and css it is all about the browser and you need to select background color on the browser print preview window ;)

Comment: It's not really clear, but I guess what's happening is that some elements are dropped because they are hidden in the print stylesheet.

Comment: then how can i make them visible?

Comment: 1. Are the elements only hidden in the preview (do they appear in the final printout)? 2. Are the elements completely missing or cut off/clipped? What is the CSS of the elements which are invisible in the preview?

Comment: actually i have 4 pages these are simple HTML pages just difference in their content and this is happening with each page

Comment: i didn't try to print but saving to .pdf there is also the same issue

Comment: @Ma6139735 could you share at least some html that has the reproductible behaviour here so people can give you a more concrete solution.

Comment: @Loïc Faure-Lacroix I am doing this for .aspx code

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to put everything you want to print in a media query in CSS:

```
@media print {
    .myDivToPrint {
        background-color: white;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 15px;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 18px;
    }
}
```